# php: replace string in range

Tags: php, string, binary

I have a large (~6MB) binary "string".
Now i'd like to replace some bytes withing a range of the string.

Let's say, replace substring (binary, bytes) from offset 1024 with length 84 with another string (binary, bytes) with the **same length** (no data extending).

How can i do this with php so that the performance will not be very bad.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) will create a new string and return its value; assigning it to the same variable should free its old value.

```
$s = substr_replace($s, $replacement, 1024, 84);
```